# C++ Synchronization Library

Tags: c++, c++11

I was trying to learn various Thread Synchronization Techniques and understand that they are as mentioned below:

```
Mutex
Condition Variable
Semaphores
```

Please add if I missed any - however I found that we do not have C++ semaphore APIs available as like in C (semget , sem_wait , sem_init)

Am I true in my understating?

Comment: `promise` `futurw`?

Comment: `semget` is POSIX, not C. The POSIX library generally can be used from both C and C++, but C++ often has more convenient options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's quite a bunch. `std::promise` and `std::future` as mentioned by πάντα ῥεῖ in the comments, but also `std::call_once`. (These are all C++11, as tagged)

C++20 adds the `<semaphore>` header, and also `<latch>`.

Comment: Its strange - why semaphore library features is inducted in C++ so late?

Comment: @Programmer: Semaphores are chiefly a theoretical building block by Dijkstra. Real CPU's don't implement semaphores. C++ does offer the higher-level, useful building blocks which can be implemented using the available CPU constructs directly.

Answer (score 0):

Semaphores only [arrived in C++/20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/counting_semaphore). If your compiler has an option to use it, you’re good.

If you don’t have C++/20, you can wrap C APIs yourself, or you can emulate with a combination of `std::mutex` and `std::condition_variable`.